# Pattern to replace nested conditionals with guard clauses while still performing some action for the vast majority of cases but not all

Tags: java, goto, control-flow

I've got a method that kind follows the following pattern:

```
void myMethod(String arg1) {
  SomeObject foo = getSomeObject(arg1);

  if(foo != null) {
    SomeOtherObject bar = foo.getSomeOtherObject();

    if(bar != null) {
      bar.doSomething();

      if(bar.isGood()) {
        YetAnother baz = getAnotherByName(bar.getAnotherName());

        if(baz != null) {
          if(baz.exitEarly()) {
            foo.recordEarlyExit(baz.getName());
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  doNormalThing();
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to get the same behavior without so many levels.

If I didn't have to do `doNormalThing();` at the end, I could do something like this:

```
void myMethod(String arg1) {
  SomeObject foo = getSomeObject(arg1);
  if(foo == null) { return; }

  SomeOtherObject bar = foo.getSomeOtherObject();
  if(bar == null) { return; }

  bar.doSomething();
  if(!bar.isGood()) { return; }

  YetAnother baz = getAnotherByName(bar.getAnotherName());

  if(baz == null) { return; }

  if(baz.exitEarly()) {
    foo.recordEarlyExit(baz.getName());
  }
}
```

I'm basically doing the above, but add `doNormalThing();` prior to all the `return`s. But that's a lot of repetition and if I need to change something, I have to do it in all those blocks.

I could do something like wrap it in a `try{ ... } catch (DoNormalThingException e) { doNormalThing(); }` and only throw `DoNormalThingException` when I want to call that method prior to returning from the method, and not throw it when `baz.exitEarly()` is true. But that doesn't seem clean either, and seems like it's abusing exceptions.

If it was just checking for `null` in all the conditionals, then I could wrap in a `try` and only run `doNormalThing()` when a `NullPointerException` is thrown. It's a a lot cleaner than the other exception based way: I wouldn't need any conditionals, and I'm catching a legit exception, not a made up one just being used for control flow. But not all the checks are for `== null` and I wouldn't want to mask NPEs coming from deeper method calls.

If only java had `goto`...

Edit: So I knew this type of refactoring had a name, it's: Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses. This is what I attempted to do, but it doesn't work well if you have that extra method that needs to be called in most cases but not all. Still, I thought I'd mention it to help others find this question.

Comment: Could you call `doNormalThing()` after `myMethod()` instead of inside it? I actually prefer the nested `if`s rather than the early `return`s though.

Comment: Not easily, since `doNormalThing()` isn't always called. I suppose I could have `myMethod()` changed to return a value indicating whether `doNormalThing()` should be called... Unfortunately, `myMethod()` is actually the implementation of a method of an interface which is called by other code, and I can't change its signature or how it's called.

Comment: Sounds like your first example is as clean as you'll get then, if you're bound to using a specific method signature. Like I said, I don't think the nested `if`s are that 'unclean'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to wrap all but the `doNormalThing` method call in another method that returns whether or not to execute `doNormalThing` afterwards:

```
void myMethod(String arg1) {
    if (myMethodInternal(arg1)) {
        doNormalThing();
    }
}

private boolean myMethodInternal(String arg1) {
    SomeObject foo = getSomeObject(arg1);
    if (foo == null) {
        return true;
    }

    SomeOtherObject bar = goo.getSomeOtherObject();
    if (bar == null) {
        return true;
    }
    // etc

    if (baz.exitEarly()) {
        foo.recordEarlyExit(baz.getName());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It doesn't feel terribly clean, but it would at least work. You *could* also use `try/finally` without the exception - using a `boolean` field to determine whether or not to execute `doNormalThing`.

Comment: As I mentioned to @andrew-mairose, I can't change the signature of the method, nor how it's called. The `try/finally` with a boolean is an option though, I might see how that looks.

Comment: @onlynone: I didn't suggest changing the signature of the method - look at my code... the "externally visible" method has the same signature as before.  It calls a new *private* method which returns `boolean`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, sorry I didn't read as closely. I think I still might prefer the `try/finally` though.

Comment: @onlynone: The problem with that is you'll end up calling doNormalThing even in the face of an exception unless you're careful.

Comment: Marking this one as the answer as it came closest to what I wanted. I'm actually going with the `try/finally` approach, but if things were slightly different in my code, I could see the given answer working. I also liked @marstran's `Optional` approach below.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by composing Java 8 Optionals like this:

```
void myMethod(String arg1) {
    SomeObject foo = getSomeObject(arg1);

    Optional<SomeOtherObject> opBar = 
                Optional.ofNullable(foo)
                        .map(foo -> foo.getSomeOtherObject())

    opBar.ifPresent(bar -> bar.doSomething());

    Optional<YetAnother> opBaz = 
                  opBar.filter(bar -> bar.isGood())
                       .map(bar -> getAnotherByName(bar.getAnotherName())
                       .filter(baz -> baz.exitEarly());

    opBaz.ifPresent(baz -> foo.recordEarlyExit(baz.getName()));

    if (!opBaz.isPresent()) {
        doNormalThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. Unfortunately my case is a little more complicated than my example, plus I don't know if it's definitely clearer.

Comment: Yes, it gets cluttered by the `void` methods like `bar.doSomething()` and `foo.recordEarlyExit(baz.getName())`. It would get cleaner if they were returning a new object, instead of relying on their side effects.